# React Native Navigation : A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, react-native-navigation

#### Bug Report

I've started learning [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing) and I failed to launch the app with the implementation of basic navigation code.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Run : `npm install --save react-native-navigation`.
2. Write the code of [basic navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/basic-navigation).
3. Run : `npx react-native start`.
4. Run : `npx react-native run-android`.

#### Expected Behaviour

[image]

#### Current Behaviour

```
alaeddine@Ala-Dev:~/Apps/GitaApp$ npx react-native run-android
warn Package react-native-navigation contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed,"dependency.hooks" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/alaeddine/Apps/GitaApp/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/alaeddine/Apps/GitaApp/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

    at makeError (/home/alaeddine/Apps/GitaApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/alaeddine/Apps/GitaApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/alaeddine/Apps/GitaApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/alaeddine/Apps/GitaApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

#### build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and this is how i solved my problem,

1. step-1) `npm install --save react-native-navigation`
2. step-2) `npx rnn-link`
3. if `step-2` still throws erros, then follow the `Manual installation` to make changes in your project manually provided by the documentation:

->iOS. https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing#ios

->Android. https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing#android

4. step-3) write the code of [basic navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/basic-navigation#creating-a-stack)
5. step-4) Run: `npm start`
6. step-5) Run: `npm run android` (for androids)